# Dose Karate framework support headless execution for MS Edge browser on Linux?

Tags: microsoft-edge, karate

I want to execute my test scripts on [Microsoft Edge browser on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download?form=MA13FJ) server.

I have tried using `headless: true` in driver configuration. However, it's not working.

Also, tried  with driver configuration

```
* configuration driver: {type: 'msedgedriver', executable:'/edgedriver_linux64/msedgedriver', webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge', edgeOptions: { args: ['-headless'] }} }}
```

I am expecting to run test scripts in headless mode.
Is there any way to execute test scripts in headless mode?

Comment: this is an area where we invite community contributions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+edge+headless

Comment: How about the issue? May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, Karate framework doesn't support headless mode for Edge at present. You can refer to [this doc](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driver-configuration). You can find the following information in the Driver Configuration table:

> headless mode only applies to `{ type: 'chrome' }` for now, also see `DockerTarget` and `webDriverSession`